# Android CalendarView Year Text Color

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, calendarview

I'm styling the CalendarView in Android Studio and I already achieved to change the selected color

with the following code:

layout:

```
<CalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/CalenderViewCustom"
        android:dateTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewDateCustomText"
        android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewWeekCustomText">
    </CalendarView>
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="CalenderViewCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/mainSelectedColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CalenderViewDateCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CalenderViewWeekCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
    </style>
```

The problem is that my result does not show the year and the month like you can see in the result:

[image]

I already tried to change the header attributes like headerMonthTextApperance but nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you cant use this library

> https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView

full performance and customizable

```
<com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/compactcalendar_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:compactCalendarTargetHeight="250dp"
        app:compactCalendarTextSize="12sp"
        app:compactCalendarBackgroundColor="#ffe95451"
        app:compactCalendarTextColor="#fff"
        app:compactCalendarCurrentSelectedDayBackgroundColor="#E57373"
        app:compactCalendarCurrentDayBackgroundColor="#B71C1C"
        app:compactCalendarMultiEventIndicatorColor="#fff"
        />
```